# Svelte custom store subscribe and local forage

Tags: svelte, svelte-store

I'm trying to update local forage upon any changes to the store.

I know this can be done by this:

```js
import { writable } from "svelte/store";
import localforage from "localforage";

const stored = await localforage.getItem("tasks");

const createTasks = () => {
    const { subscribe, set, update } = writable(stored || []);
    return {
        subscribe,
        add: (newTask) => {
            update((tasks) => [{ content: newTask }, ...tasks]);
        },
    };
};

export const tasks = createTasks();

// Is there another way to do this?
tasks.subscribe(async (val) => {
    await localforage.setItem("tasks", val);
});
```

But how can I do this within the `createTasks` function instead of `tasks.subscribe(...)`.

---

**Follow-up After Answer**

It was working for the test snippet above but it's resulting to a "Error: 'bleeps' is not a store with a 'subscribe' method" for the below code.

```js
const createBleeps = async () => {
    const { subscribe, update, set } = writable(
        (await localforage.getItem("bleeper_bleeps")) || []
    );

    subscribe(async (val) => {
        await localforage.setItem("bleeper_bleeps", val);
    });

    return {
        subscribe,
        set,
        update: () => update((bleeps) => bleeps),
        add: (newBleep) =>
            update((bleeps) => [
                {
                    id: uuidv4(),
                    content: newBleep.content,
                    interval: newBleep.interval,
                    prevInterval: null,
                    intervalID: null,
                    clickToConfirm: false,
                    isActive: true,
                },
                ...bleeps,
            ]),
        remove: (bleepId) =>
            update((bleeps) => bleeps.filter((bleep) => bleep.id !== bleepId)),
    };
};

export const bleeps = createBleeps();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the code into the function:

```js
const createTasks = () => {
    const { subscribe, set, update } = writable(stored || []);

    subscribe(async (val) => {
        await localforage.setItem("tasks", val);
    });

    return {
        subscribe,
        add: (newTask) => {
            update((tasks) => [{ content: newTask }, ...tasks]);
        },
    };
};
```

Comment: I just added a follow up in the question. Could you take a look at it as well? It's saying there is no subscribe method in the store. But I'm doing the same thing as your snippet.

Comment: The error seems unrelated to the code, it sounds like you are trying to use `$` syntax with an object that is not a store. Please, if anything, post a separate question and include all the relevant code.